# Observable is not working in case of button click

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a json with "id" element and i am passing that "id" in a textbox and want to find change color of respective item in below list on button click.

Js Code:

```
   var bugTracker=function(){
    var self=this;
    self.bugId=ko.observable(),
    self.bugList=ko.observableArray([
    {id:1,name:"Abc"},{id:2,name:"Dooo"},{id:3,name:"Usss"},{id:4,name:"Yeess"}
    ])
    self.currentSelectedId=ko.observable(0);

    self.getSelected=function(data){
    console.log(self.bugId());
    this.currentSelectedId(self.bugId());
    console.log(this.currentSelectedId());
    }

    self.getClicked=function(data){
    //console.log(self.bugName());
    this.currentSelectedId(data.id);
    console.log(this.currentSelectedId());
    }

   }

   $(function(){
   ko.applyBindings(new bugTracker());
   });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
    <label>Enter Bug Id:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value : bugId" >
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: getSelected" value="Select Item"/>
    <ol data-bind="foreach : bugList">
        <li data-bind="text : name,css:{'filteredItemTex': id===$parent.currentSelectedId()},'click': function(){$parent.getClicked($data);}" >
        </li>
    </ol>

</div>
```

Css:

```
.filteredItemTex{
        color:red;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `bugId` is bound to a textbox so its value is a string. `id === $parent.currentSelectedId()` fails because `===` is doing a strict comparison.

You can change it to a `==`, or use `parseInt`:

```
self.getSelected = function(data) {
    console.log(self.bugId());
    this.currentSelectedId(parseInt(self.bugId()));
    console.log(this.currentSelectedId());
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79gto4qx/